# Encrypt and decrypt from Javascript (nodeJS) to dart (Flutter) and from dart to Javascript

Tags: javascript, flutter, encryption, dart, rsa

As the title suggests, I would like to know if there is a way to encrypt and decrypt, using for example the RSA algorithm, data from javascript to dart and the opposite. I saw that there is a library, 'js', which allows you to use javascript code in dart but I was not able to use it for what I need. I tried also to use various libraries provided for both languages ​​to perform these encryption operations but they are not compatible between the two languages.

Answer (score 5):

**Keygen (NodeJS)**

Docs: https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_generatekeypair_type_options_callback

```
const { generateKeyPair } = require('crypto');

generateKeyPair('rsa', {
    modulusLength: 4096,    // key size in bits
    publicKeyEncoding: {
        type: 'spki',
        format: 'pem',
    },
    privateKeyEncoding: {   
        type: 'pkcs8',      
        format: 'pem',
    },
}, (err, publicKey, privateKey) => {
    // Handle errors and use the generated key pair.
});
```

**NodeJS** encryption via **JSEncrypt** library

node-jsencrypt: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-jsencrypt
JSEncrypt: https://travistidwell.com/jsencrypt/#

```
const JSEncrypt = require('node-jsencrypt');  

function encrypt(text, key) {
    const crypt = new JSEncrypt();
    crypt.setKey(key);
    return crypt.encrypt(text);
}

function decrypt(encrypted, privateKey) {
    const crypt = new JSEncrypt();
    crypt.setPrivateKey(privateKey);
    return crypt.decrypt(encrypted);
}
```

**Dart** encryption via **crypton**

GitHub: https://github.com/konstantinullrich/crypton

```
import 'package:crypton/crypton.dart';

import 'encryption.dart';

class AsymmetricCrypt implements Encryption {
  final String _key;
  RSAPublicKey _publicKey;
  RSAPrivateKey _privateKey;

  AsymmetricCrypt._(this._key);

  @override
  String encrypt(String plain) {
    _publicKey ??= RSAPublicKey.fromPEM(_key);
    return _publicKey.encrypt(plain);
  }

  @override
  String decrypt(String data) {
    _privateKey ??= RSAPrivateKey.fromPEM(_key);
    return _privateKey.decrypt(data);
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, I've been looking for so long for a full response. This works perfectly with NodeJS and Flutter.

Comment: Where is the file import 'encryption.dart';?? Don´t reference in the example code...

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/pointycastle) for your crypto needs including RSA keys/ciphers.

Comment: i saw the pointycastle package(dart) and cryptoJS (NodeJS) but i don't know how i can merge pointycastle with cryptoJS

Answer (score 1):

***Symmetric Javascript - Flutter/Dart compatible encryption package.***

This was a beneficial post & helped me with Asymmetric as above.

I am creating a hybrid crypto system, here is what I played around with to get the symmetric version working:

[Package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js)

[Docs](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/)

[Implementation help I got](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70819452/trouble-using-cryptojs-parsing-from-decrypted-format-to-string-with-most-padding?noredirect=1#comment125199312_70819452)

[Flutter Package- SteelCrypt](https://pub.dev/packages/steel_crypt/example)

The code is rough but it basically shows all the encoding required on the JS end to get proper output on the Flutter end. Flutter end is a piece of cake AS LONG AS YOU GET THE ENCODING RIGHT IN JS ;)

Implementation encryption in Javascript:

```
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
  try {
    var JsonFormatter = {
  stringify: function(cipherParams) {
    // create json object with ciphertext
    var jsonObj = { ct: cipherParams.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64) };

    // optionally add iv or salt
    if (cipherParams.iv) {
      jsonObj.iv = cipherParams.iv.toString();
    }

    // stringify json object
    return JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
  },
  parse: function(jsonStr) {
    // parse json string
    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);

    // extract ciphertext from json object, and create cipher params object
    var cipherParams = CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create({
      ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(jsonObj.ct)
    });

    // optionally extract iv or salt

    if (jsonObj.iv) {
      cipherParams.iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(jsonObj.iv);
    }

    return cipherParams;
  }
};

var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", "Secret Passphrase", {
  format: JsonFormatter
});
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, "Secret Passphrase", {
  format: JsonFormatter
});
decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

    return {
    "key": CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(encrypted.key),
    "iv": CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(encrypted.iv),
    "encrypted": CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(encrypted.ciphertext),
    "decrypted": decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8),
  }
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error);
  }
```

Returns

```
{
key: Y4GKaFmHD9fPBh/LI04nooA3WVoBWSIkd0GzqJkX7fA=,
iv: DlNlgIv+Vboxq8MSrIFtVA==,
encrypted: NduRQJ7CB40r18w4meeIoQ==,
decrypted: Message
}
```

Flutter/Dart implementation:

```
//AES CBC decryption from Parse CryptoJS
  var iv = 'DlNlgIv+Vboxq8MSrIFtVA==';
  var key = 'Y4GKaFmHD9fPBh/LI04nooA3WVoBWSIkd0GzqJkX7fA=';
  var cypher = AesCrypt(key: key, padding: PaddingAES.pkcs7);
  var encryptedData = 'NduRQJ7CB40r18w4meeIoQ==';
  print(cypher.cbc.decrypt(enc: encryptedData, iv: iv)); //decrypt
```

Prints

```
Message
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 'aescryptojs' package on the flutter side and 'crypto-js' on the node.js side. This way the AES algorithms will work consistently on both client and sever side.

Flutter:

```
class DataEncrypt {
  static wrappingEncrypted(dynamic data) {
    // Todo: datanin sifrelenmesi islemi
    final unencryptedData = data;
    final key = '${dotenv.env['ENCRYPT_KEY']}';
    final encryptedData = encryptAESCryptoJS(unencryptedData, key);
    print("Encrypted data :" + encryptedData);
    return encryptedData;
  }

  static wrappingDescrypted(dynamic data) {
    // Todo: sifrenin cozumlenmesi islemi
    final key = '${dotenv.env['ENCRYPT_KEY']}';
    final descryptedData = decryptAESCryptoJS(data, key);
    print("Descrypted data :" + descryptedData);
    return descryptedData;
  }
}
```

Node.js:

```
function funcDecryptedData(data) {
    // Todo: AES Decrypted
    var bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(data, process.env.ENCRYPT_KEY);
    var descryptedData = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    return descryptedData;
}
function funcEncryptedData(data) {
    //Todo: AES Encrypted
    var encryptedData = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, process.env.ENCRYPT_KEY).toString();
    return encryptedData;
}
```