# How do I encrypt data from a frontend flutter to a backend nodejs and vice versa?

Tags: node.js, typescript, flutter, aes, rsa

I am currently sending data back and forth between flutter and nodeJS. I wanted to secure the data that is being sent so I found this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59586980/encrypt-and-decrypt-from-javascript-nodejs-to-dart-flutter-and-from-dart-to) on stack overflow of exactly what I need to do. This is great and all. However, there are 2 issues that arise.

1. The answer does not really answer the question fully and leaves me wondering how the code provided will be used.
2. JSEncrypt when installed using both `npm i jsencrypt` and `npm i @types/jsencrypt` I always get the same `ReferenceError` stating that `window is undefined` in `jsencrypt.cs` on line 18. I tried looking for answers to this issue but I haven't found anything that has worked, including:

setting global.window to jsdom window
setting globalThis.window to a jsdom window

So my question is:

1. Can I encrypt and decrypt using RSA just like the post but in a clearer and error-free way?

or

2. Is there a way I can encrypt and decrypt using AES 256-bit? (I would prefer this a lot more) between flutter and node js?